# Querying Data Views - finding Email Address

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Data views track subscriber engagement on SubscriberKey, is it possible to see the email address used at time of send? I'm able to pull Email Address from _Subscribers, but that is the current Email Address value which could have differed than what was used at time of send.

Can this be pulled through data views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of **_Subscribers**, I don't think it's retrievable.

You could record the email address at the time of send using the [**SendLog**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/) and then retrieve it in your Query Activity.

This wouldn't really help you with previous sends, but it would work going forward.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Adam. I know Tracking Extract data includes the email address attribute. Do you know if that value is the email address used at time of send?

Comment: You'd have to test it. I'm guessing it's not the email address at time of send.